# Regex to append character and remove end double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried below regex to capture some string out of it :

```
    "CallbackFnCreate_[\W]{4}(.*?[^\w-])

Required Output should be : /TestResult_20190604-120620 (Capture 
TestResult_20190604-120620 and append "/" in the beginning)
```

My Group 1 Output is  : TestResult_20190604-120620"

```
1|#||4|3952|updatePanel|WorkflowFileExplorer_ajaxPanel|<div `id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pbContainer" style="width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><input type="button" name="WorkflowFileExplorer$pb" value="pb" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;WorkflowFileExplorer$pb&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pb" tabindex="-1" /><input name="WorkflowFileExplorer$postbackArgument" type="hidden" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_postbackArgument" value="CallbackFnCreate_/***TestResult_20190604-120620" /></div><div id="WorkflowFileExplorer_tree" class="RadTreeView RadTreeView_Default">`
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that we wish to simply do a replacement and slightly modify the original expression:

```
.+("CallbackFnCreate_\/\*\*\*(.+?)").+
```

which our desired output is here in this capturing group:

```
(.+?)
```

#### Test

```js
const regex = /.+("CallbackFnCreate_\/\*\*\*(.+?)").+/gm;
const str = `1|#||4|3952|updatePanel|WorkflowFileExplorer_ajaxPanel|<div \`id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pbContainer" style="width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><input type="button" name="WorkflowFileExplorer\$pb" value="pb" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;WorkflowFileExplorer\$pb&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pb" tabindex="-1" /><input name="WorkflowFileExplorer\$postbackArgument" type="hidden" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_postbackArgument" value="CallbackFnCreate_/***TestResult_20190604-120620" /></div><div id="WorkflowFileExplorer_tree" class="RadTreeView RadTreeView_Default">\`
`;
const subst = `\/$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: I cannot write custom code like regex.replace since this need to be done in Jmeter window it only supports pure regex something like (.+("CallbackFnCreate_\/\*\*\*(.+?)").+ , is there a way to substitute/append ('/") in this ?

Comment: It gives me /***TestResult_20190604-120620 , i want /TestResult_20190604-120620

Comment: The way i see it is as , i will use this (CallbackFnCreate_(\/(?:***).+?)") it will give me /***TestResult_20190604-120620 , not able to figure out how to remove those 3 asterik, i require it as /TestResult_20190604-120620

Answer (score 1):

Just use parentheses to capture the relevant part and append the "/" at replacement.

```js
var re = /.+"CallbackFnCreate_\/\W{3}([^"]+).+/;
var text = '1|#||4|3952|updatePanel|WorkflowFileExplorer_ajaxPanel|<div `id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pbContainer" style="width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><input type="button" name="WorkflowFileExplorer$pb" value="pb" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;WorkflowFileExplorer$pb&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pb" tabindex="-1" /><input name="WorkflowFileExplorer$postbackArgument" type="hidden" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_postbackArgument" value="CallbackFnCreate_/***TestResult_20190604-120620" /></div><div id="WorkflowFileExplorer_tree" class="RadTreeView RadTreeView_Default">`';

var res = text.replace(re, '/$1')

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I cannot write custom code like regex.replace since this need to be done in Jmeter window it only supports pure regex something like (.+("CallbackFnCreate_\/***(.+?)").+ , is there a way to substitute/append ('/") in this ?

Comment: Well can you capture multiple parts and append them at least?
Otherwise I see no way of doing what you ask for with just one capture and no string concatenation of any sort.

Comment: The way i see it is as , i will use this (CallbackFnCreate_(\/(?:\*\*\*).+?)") it will give me /***TestResult_20190604-120620 , not able to figure out how to remove those 3 asterik, i require it as /TestResult_20190604-120620

Comment: You cannot merge captures so either you can capture the "/" and then just append the two captured elements, or you can append the "/" directly at the end. Otherwise what you ask for is simply impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capturing group an in the replacement place a forward slash between before the first capturing group.

```
"CallbackFnCreate_\/\*{3}([^"]+)(?=")
```

**Explanation**

- `"CallbackFnCreate_` Match literally
- `\/\*{3}` match `/` and 3 times `*`
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^"]+` Match 1+ times not a `"`
- `)` Close capturing group
- `(?=")` Assert what is on the right is a `"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r3i6Bx/1)

```js
const regex = /"CallbackFnCreate_\/\*{3}([^"\n]+)(?=")/;
const str = `1|#||4|3952|updatePanel|WorkflowFileExplorer_ajaxPanel|<div \`id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pbContainer" style="width:0px;height:0px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;"><input type="button" name="WorkflowFileExplorer\$pb" value="pb" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;WorkflowFileExplorer\$pb&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_pb" tabindex="-1" /><input name="WorkflowFileExplorer\$postbackArgument" type="hidden" id="WorkflowFileExplorer_postbackArgument" value="CallbackFnCreate_/***TestResult_20190604-120620" /></div><div id="WorkflowFileExplorer_tree" class="RadTreeView RadTreeView_Default">\``;
let res = str.match(regex);
console.log("/" + res[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const unformattedName = 'CallbackFnCreate_/***TestResult_20190604-120620"';
const found = unformattedName.match(/CallbackFnCreate_(\/)[\W]{3}(.*?[^\w-])/);

document.write(found[1]+found[2]);
```

The first capturing group is (/) this will match the "/" then the second capturing group which is (.*?[^\w-]) will match the "TestResult_20190604-120620".

More explanation below....

1) the (/) \ is backslash and is used to escape the "/" since / is a special character in regular expressions it tells javascript that this is just a string and not a special character. Therefore the "/" is matched.

2) [\W]{3}--- this is not a group since it is not in brackets. [\W] means capture any non-word [\W]{3} means capture three consecutive non words which in your case is ***.

3) (.*?[^\w-])-----  .* means capture any amount of characters except newline. Literally it is meant to capture all characters but the "?" makes it lazy .*? therefore means that it should capture all characters but should try to keep it at minimum. [^\w-] means it should capture any character that is not a word i.e [a-zA-Z0-9_] and should not capture"-" too. therefore .*?[^\w-]-- means capture all characters but stop after the first non word character except -; this is group 2.

4) group 1 -- will output = /
group 2 -- will output = 'TestResult_20190604-120620"';